# EXPECT_CALL check if parameter contains given subset

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock, matcher

I'm using gtest & gmock and want to set expectations on a function that is called with a set. I want to make sure this set contains several elements.

Something like this:

`EXPECT_CALL(*mView, SetHighlightedCells(Contains(AllOf(c5, c6))));`

I know I can specify the full set,

`EXPECT_CALL(*mView, SetHighlightedCells(UnorderedElementsAre(c5, c6, ...and all the rest..)));`

or

`EXPECT_CALL(*mView, SetHighlightedCells(UnorderedElementsAreArray(vector_containing_c5_c6_and_ALL_other_elements)));`

But I'm not interested in all other elements passed, I only need to make sure this set contains `c5` and `c6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the docs `AllOf()` takes a bunch of matchers, of which one of is:

> `Contains(e)`
>    argument contains an element that matches e, which can be either a value or a matcher.

So I would guess:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mView, SetHighlightedCells(AllOf(Contains(c5), Contains(c6))));
```

Comment: Yes. You are correct, didn't think about it this way :) I'll accept the answer as soon it lets me do it.